# CodeIgniter Session stopped working

Tags: codeigniter

CodeIgniter Session worked well. But after I reinstall Vagrant Homestead, Session doesn't work. No any changes in code. I tried to change `$config['sess_driver']` to '`files`', '`memcached`', but same problem. I see session data in files. Afer refreshing a page it's like no logged user.

I event don't know where is the problem.

Comment: Is it possible that, during your reinstall of Vagrant, the php.ini file changed?

Comment: I didn't change php.ini before

Answer (score 1):

I just upgraded CodeIgniter version to last one. This problem happens with CodeIgniter 3.0 and PHP 7.1